# display similar variation products to same page - WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce

It is not that tricky as it sounds in the title.

**I have rugs to sell on WooCommerce:**
Variable product: Rug1: small, medium, large
Variable product: Rug2: small, medium, large
and so on..

I want to display all the small rugs in one page, medium in another, and large in another.

Please suggest!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code ....

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation'=>'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'pa_size',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'small'
        )
    )
) );
```

Add post type = product to the query and place it to your desired templates.

Comment: Hi Alice, Thanks for your answer. BUT,, Can you elaborate: Where to insert the above code, and how would I create a page to display those products?